# How can I create an instance of a struct, that will not be deleted when it is out of scope?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am trying to create a custom data structure in C++, something that resembles to a double linked list. So inside a class constructor I am creating an instance of a struct (see code below), but I can't "save" it when I am changing scopes.

I have tried to create the instance with the keyword new, but when I run my programm with the debugger I see that the objects that I created in the previous scope are "optimized out".

By previous scope I mean when I am in a scope of a if loop, and then I enter another if statement and it seems like the instances I created in the first one are gone.

I am not sure what "optimized out" actually means. I am using CLion and that was the message it showed in the debugger when I changed scope.

The code for the struct is:

```
struct singleLinkNode {
    int column;
    int data;
    singleLinkNode *nextSingleNode;
};
```

My goal is to create an instance of a struct that remains in memory until I delete it or the programm ends.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `new` is the right way. What do you mean by "previous scope" and "optimized out"? Show a [mcve] that demonstrates this supposed behavior.

Comment: Are you actually asking for a _Singleton_?

Comment: "*So inside a class constructor I am creating an instance of a struct (see code below), but I can't "save" it when I am changing scopes.*" So why not make it a class member? In any event, unless we can see what you're trying to do with it, we can't really answer your question.

Comment: [Implementing a singly linked list with smart pointers](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/02/22/cpp-17-implementing-singly-linked-list-smart-pointers/) ...

Comment: Hang on... are you creating instances inside a loop with the *same name*?  Block scope occurs for compound statements (anything brace-enclosed, including multi-line bodies for loops and conditionals), but they should only shadow if there's a name conflict.
Would declaring an array outside your loop and creating the loop instances as array elements work?   *(edit: right, right.  c++.  ahem, "a vector outside your loop...")*

Comment: This must be it, because I create the instances in a nested for loop. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

"Optimized out" means

> compiler didn't find any use of this variable, so it decided it's not needed and removed it from generated assembly

When your code will start using this variable (i.e. reading and writing to it), it will not be optimized out anymore.

Alternatively, you can turn off your compiler optimizations (in gcc that would be done with `-O0` flag).

As noted by Igor Tandetnik in comments, `new` keyword creates an object and puts it on the heap. This object will live until you call `delete` or your program finishes.
However, compiler noticed that pointer created with `new` is never used, so it optimized it away (possibly with the whole object, but that's unknown).

Comment: "optimized out" in the debugger generally just means that the debugger hasn't got enough information to find where that at object is. In optimized builds happens quite often even if the object is alive and reachable from the program code; not saying that this is necessarily the case, but it's important to have this very clear when debugging optimized binaries.